# Split Collection by Object Property

Tags: groovy

I'm looking for a way to split/sort a collection by object's property. For example:

```
def oList = [[height:13, name:'bob'], [height: 9, name:'cat'], [height: 13, name: 'foo']]
// output [[[height:13, name:'bob'], [height: 13, name: 'foo']], [[height: 9, name:'cat']]]
```

Results would be grouping object in the list into sub-list with matching `height`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
oList.groupBy { it.height }.values()
```